# Available options for angular client side error tracking?

Tags: angular, error-handling, frontend

I am currently working on a angular 7 SPA, which is a very heavy application on the client side. 
There could be scenarios that front end may fail due to some data issues, or maybe due to some script failures. 
Here I am looking for some recommendations for the client side error tracking. I can think of a custom framework where we get errors shipped to the backend and store. But I am looking for a standard 3rd party API which supports error handling + some miscellaneous app management features. **Raygun** is one of the options I came across, can you suggest me any other ones having a good experience.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Sentry. It's self-hosted and cloud-based error monitoring that helps to discover, triage, and prioritize errors in real-time. It support each version of Angular. Really useful.

Here is a description how to configure it inside Angular app: [Sentry Angular Doc](https://sentry.io/for/angular2/).